# In web server the CSS and JS references are not known

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I loaded my ASP.NET MVC project in the web server but unfortunately none of my CSS and JS references are loaded. Some of my references in my defaultlayout are as below:

```
    <head>
        <link href="/Scripts/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/Scripts/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/Scripts/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/Scripts/css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/Scripts/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/Scripts/css/icon_fonts/css/all_icons_min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/Scripts/css/skins/square/grey.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link href="/Scripts/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="/Scripts/js/modernizr.js"></script>
        <link href="/Content/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Scripts/Chosen/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/Scripts/css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div id="form_container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <div id="wizard_container">
                        <div id="top-wizard">
                            <div id="progressbar"></div>
                        </div>
                        @RenderBody()
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="/Content/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/js/common_scripts_min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/js/registration_wizard_func.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/js/velocity.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/js/functions.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/js/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
    <script src="/Scripts/Chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

How can I fix this problem. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Might be path is wrong: `/Scripts/css/bootstrap.min.css`, try: `./Scripts/css/bootstrap.min.css` or show us the file directory structure\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `~` to the beginning of source.

Example :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/js/common_scripts_min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use `..` and see how about it? `~` and `..`  both refer to the beginning of the application path .